# Fill Listbox with values from TextFile

Tags: c#, file-io, io, listbox

i have a issue with my code. My code has to read out values from a textfiles, which it does. But when i put the values of the textfile in my listbox it comes out like this:

[image: commandlistbox]

So the commands or values are coming in one line. 
I want the commands to go like this, I've changed the picture so you can see:

[image]

So you see? I want the commands under each other. This is my code for reading the textfile:

```
private void CommandFileSelectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream mystream;
        OpenFileDialog commandFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();


        if (commandFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((mystream = commandFileDialog.OpenFile())!= null)
            {
                string fileName = commandFileDialog.FileName;
                CommandListTextBox.Text = fileName;
                string fileText = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
                _commandList.Add(fileText);
                CommandListListBox.DataSource = _commandList;
            }

        }
    }
```

`_commandList` is an local functions which my co worker has made.

This is how to `TextFile` looks:

```
RUN 
RUNW
STOP
RUN
RUN
STOP
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: you can add new line after each fileText.

Comment: Can you explain a little more so i can see what you mean?

Comment: are the commands in file are on separate lines or they are in same line??

Comment: The command are on separate lines

Comment: read them line-by-line instead of using `ReadAllText`

Comment: Instead of `string File.ReadAllText()` use `string[] File.ReadAllLines()` and use `foreach` loop to add separate lines.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: i've did this: CommandListListBox.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines(fileName) and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this !

```
// Open the file to read from. 
 string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        foreach (string fileText in readText)
        {
            _commandList.Add(fileText);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CommandListListBox.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

If `_commandList` is of type `System.Collection.Generic.List<string>` you can use the following snippet:

```
_commandList.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName));
```

---

Full code:

```
private void CommandFileSelectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream mystream;
    OpenFileDialog commandFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();


    if (commandFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if ((mystream = commandFileDialog.OpenFile())!= null)
        {
            string fileName = commandFileDialog.FileName;
            CommandListTextBox.Text = fileName;
            _commandList.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName));
            CommandListListBox.DataSource = _commandList;
        }

    }
}
```